# React Native Firebase installation does not work

Tags: android, json, firebase, react-native

Hi I'm following the guidelines of https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/installation/initial-setup to install firebase for React Native. I'm using an Android Emulator.

After everything is done I cannot start the application. That's what happens when starting the app via 'react-native run-android':

Parsing json file: C:\Users\Studium\WebstormProjects\app-programming\android\app\google-services.json
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Failed to create folder: C:\Users\Studium\WebstormProjects\app-programming\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 25.864 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Does someone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), you can get google-services.json file and place it in android/app directory and get googleServices-info.plist file and place it in /ios directory

if you want to use analytics only use [firebase analytics](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-firebase-analytics) it works for me.

Comment: That's what I did for Android and what the guidelines is saying. I've no idea why it's not possible to create this folder. Running in administrator mode does not work either.